# For what $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ is $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to find the $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$,  i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

In class we have already shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, so I know that c=1 is possible.

If $c=0\in\mathbb{Q}$, then we would have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, which is not possible since $\sqrt{3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, I am not sure if I have to prove this further.

So know considering $c\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, I followed the prove for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$:

$"\supseteq"$: Since $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, then $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, by the closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

$"\subseteq"$: Since $(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}=1\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}=c\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$. Therefore, $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+(c\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})=2c\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$. And since $\frac{1}{2c}\in\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$, $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$. Using the same procedure we can show that $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes correct....

Comment: For an extension $M\mid_{K}$ and $\alpha\in M$ ,$K(\alpha)$ is the smallest (sub) field containing all rationalls and $\alpha$ . So if a field extension $L\mid_{K}$ contain $\alpha$ i.e $\alpha\in L$ then $K(\alpha)\subseteq L$

Comment: The equality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}}=c\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ only holds when $c = 1$. In general, you can still clear the denominator to get $c \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$, so your argument still works.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $K(a,b)|K$ is an algebraic extension and $\text{char }K=0$. You want to find $c\in K$, so that $K(c)=K(a,b)$. There's a simple algorithm you can use. Let $f, g$ be the minimal polynomials of $a, b$ over $K$, respectively. Let $Z$ be the splitting field of $f\cdot g$ (so the splitting field of both polynomials). Then you have $$f= \prod_{i=1}^r (x-a_i), \: g=\prod_{i=1}^s (x-b_i), $$
with $r, s$ the degrees of $f, g$. You can assume $a=a_1, b=b_1$. We now want to find $\lambda \in K$, such that $a+\lambda\cdot b\neq a_i+\lambda \cdot b_j$ for all $i=1,\ldots, r$ and $j=2,\ldots, s$. You will always find such a $\lambda$, because you've only excluded finitely many elements of $K$, which is infinite. And then set $c:= a+\lambda\cdot b$. Then you have $K(c)=K(a,b)$.

You're welcome to think about why this works (only in a field with characteristic $0$), or you can comment and I'll help you continue.
In your case, you have $$ f=(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2}), \: g=(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3}) $$ over their splitting field, and now you see why $\lambda = 1$ works (among many, many others).

Answer (score 2):

We need to decide whether $\theta=\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$.

This reduces to deciding whether $1,\theta,\theta^2,\theta^3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

We have
$$
\pmatrix{1 \\ \theta \\ \theta^2 \\ \theta^3}
=
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & c & 0 \\
2+3c^2 & 0 & 0 & 2c \\
0 & 2+9c^2 & 3+6c & 0 \\
}
\pmatrix{1 \\ \sqrt2 \\ \sqrt3 \\ \sqrt6}
$$
The determinant of the matrix is $2 c (9 c^3 - 4 c - 3)$ and so is zero for rational $c$ iff $c=0$.

This argument relies on knowing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$ and that $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt6$ is a basis.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3832301/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3922059/589

Comment: Is it enough to find the basis $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}$, to take four linearly independent elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$?

Comment: @Jaime02, exactly

Comment: Thanks you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you know some galois theory this might be useful, otherwise just ignore it.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory there is a bijection

$$\{ \text{subfields } K\supset E\supset \mathbb{Q}\} \to \{\text{subgroups of} \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\}$$
given by mapping a subfield $K\supset E\supset \mathbb{Q}$ to $\operatorname{Gal}(K/E)$ and mapping a subgroup $H\subset \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ to its fixed field $K^H=\{ x\in K : \sigma (x)=x \ \forall \sigma\in H\}$.

So the question your asking is: for which $c\in \mathbb{Q}$ do we have:  $K_c :=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3})=K^{\{1\}}$ i.e. $\operatorname{Gal}(K/K_c)=1$.

One can show that $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ consists of the identity and the field homomorphisms induced by mapping $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \mapsto \sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}$ or $\sqrt{2}\mapsto - \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}$.

Now $K_c = K^{ \{1\}}$ iff no nontrivial element of the galois group fixes $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$. Because every galois automorphism fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ one sees that $c\neq 0$ is a sufficient and necessary condition.

Comment: I am a bit new to Galois theory. If I understood correctly if $K=K_{c}$, then $|Gal(K/K_{c})|=[K:K_{c}]=1$, so there would only be the identity. What we want to see is for which $c$ the only H\subset{Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}} is the identity? And how would applying $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \mapsto \sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ look like?

Comment: It even holds $K=K_c$ iff $H=\operatorname{Gal}(K/K_c)=1$. We want to see for which $c$ the only element in $H$ is the identity. So we need to look at those elements of $G=\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ fixing $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ (these are precisely the elements of $H$). If you want to apply e.g. $\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \ \sqrt{3} \mapsto \sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ the result is $-\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ as $c\in \mathbb{Q}$. So this element of $G$ never fixes $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$. But what about mapping $\sqrt{3}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: If we map $\sqrt{3}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$, we have $\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}$ and then the only way to fix $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ is for $c=0$, because we would be mapping $\sqrt{2}+0\cdot\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore we see that for $c\neq{0}$, only the identity map fixes $\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$. And so $H=Gal(K/K_{c})=1$?

Comment: This is precisely it.